# En Ruby cual es la diferencia entre usar def y define_method?

Tags: ruby

Entiendo que `define_method` crea un método dinámicamente, pero... ¿en qué casos lo usaría?

¿Cuál es la 'ventaja' o qué es diferente en el uso, sobre crear un simple método con `def`?

Por favor no citen referencias de memoria o pasen links a la documentación oficial, porque eso justamente no dice lo que estoy preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ventaja es que puedes usar variables en la creación de un método y crear menos código cuando existen varios métodos con mínimas variaciones.
Como muestra, un ejemplo: Imagina tener un modelo `User` con un atributo `status` que define si ese usuario se encuentra en estado activo o inactivo. Además necesitas un par de métodos que te ayuden para:

- Revisar si un usuario se encuentra en un estado específico.
- Consultar en la bd todos los usuarios que se encuentren en un estado específico.

Entonces el modelo que te describo quedaría algo como esto:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Con esto podría hacer user.active? y retornaría true/false dependiendo 
  # si el usuario está activo o no
  def active?
    status == 'active'
  end

  def inactive?
    status == 'inactive'
  end

  # Acá al ejecutar User.active retornaría todos los usuarios activos
  def self.active
    where(status: 'active')
  end

  def self.inactive
    where(status: 'inactive')
  end

end
```

Todo bien hasta aquí. Ahora resulta que hay nuevos requerimientos y necesitas agregar 5 nuevos estados a tu modelo de usuario, para los cuales también deberían estar definidos los métodos que te expliqué. Podrías entonces crear los métodos, pero sería algo repetitivo, donde lo único que cambiaría es el nombre del estado. En este caso puede ser necesario algo de metaprogramación y crear los métodos de la siguiente forma:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  # Creo un arreglo con los nombres de todos los estados posibles, incluidos 
  # los 5 nuevos
  STATUS = ['active', 'inactive', 'locked', 'deceased', 'admin', 'whatever', 'asdf']

  # Y luego iterar ese arreglo para crear los métodos necesarios de cada estado
  STATUS.each do |st|

    # define_singleton_method sirve para definir métodos de clase
    define_singleton_method st do
      where(status: st)
    end

    # define_method sirve para definir métodos de instancia
    define_method "#{st}?" do
      status == st
    end

  end

end
```

Entonces de esta forma te has ahorrado escribir 14 métodos que prácticamente hacían lo mismo, además que queda un código mucho mas limpio.

Otro ejemplo claro es lo que hace internamente Rails con los nombres de variables que uno define. Por ejemplo para [crear los helpers de rutas](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9303873e57dd86a82ef69d58ed7e7af6bc7ed344/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L316) como `users_path` o `new_user_url` cuando defines `resources :users` en el archivo de rutas.

No te preocupes si en primera instancia sientes que esto no tiene mayor utilidad o no encuentras donde aplicarlo. Su uso es algo que quizás de primeras no se logra visualizar, pero a medida que tu código va creciendo, puedes sentir la necesidad de refactorizar tu código y ocupar algo de metaprogramación, donde puede llegar a serte útil.

Comment: Excelente explicacion, muchas gracias.  
Solo me pregunto porque no explican asi las cosas en las referencias oficiales...  
En definitiva viene siendo como un template de C++.  
El ejemplo que diste es perfectamente ilustrativo :)

Comment: Claro que si, gracias !!